# What happened to Joe Loder?

Tags: character, nightcrawler

In Nightcrawler [Louis Bloom](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0444232/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) sabotages the van of [Joe Loder](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0556051/?ref_=tt_cl_t4) and he has a very bad car crash.

When Louis films him being taken away, Joe is in a pretty bad shape. In my professional opinion it looked like he had a punctured lung and other severe injuries.

Did we ever find out what happened to Joe? Did he survive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### We don't know

The [**script**](http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/Nightcrawler.pdf) just describes him as

> LOU filming JOE being carried by ... **a god-awful mess** ...

The synopses say...

> Lou and Rick arrive in time for Lou to film Loder being wheeled away in a gurney, **choking on his own blood**.
>
> <sup>[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2872718/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)</sup>

---

> Lou sabotages Joe's van; when it crashes, Joe is **severely injured** and Lou records the aftermath
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_(film))</sup>